# Complex numbers - solving equation in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can you solve the following equation in the set of complex numbers?

> $$\frac{z- 1}{i-1} + \frac{z-2}{i-2} + \frac{z-3}{i-3}= 0$$

Comment: In exactly the same way as you would solve $$\frac{z- 1}{2} + \frac{z-2}{3} + \frac{z-3}{4}= 0$$. There is very little difference.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{z-1}{i-1}+\frac{z-2}{i-2}+\frac{z-3}{i-3}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{(z-1)(-i-1)}{(i-1)(-i-1)}+\frac{(z-2)(-i-2)}{(i-2)(-i-+2)}+\frac{(z-3)(-i-3)}{(i-3)(-i-3)}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{(z-1)(-i-1)}{2}+\frac{(z-2)(-i-2)}{5}+\frac{(z-3)(-i-3)}{10}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{5(z-1)(-i-1)}{10}+\frac{2(z-2)(-i-2)}{10}+\frac{(z-3)(-i-3)}{10}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{5(z-1)(-i-1)+2(z-2)(-i-2)+(z-3)(-i-3)}{10}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$5(z-1)(-i-1)+2(z-2)(-i-2)+(z-3)(-i-3)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(22+12i)-(12+8i)z=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-(12+8i)z=-22-12i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(12+8i)z=22+12i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{22+12i}{12+8i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{45}{26}-\frac{2i}{13}$$

Comment: "rationalizing" the denominators does seem to be a little more easy to follow than the brute force approach of common denominator of complex numbers.

Comment: I multiplied with ( i-1)(i-2)(i-3) and then I made a product of the denominator.  Then I got stuck. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: multiply by $(i-1)(i-2)(i-3)$ and expand.

Comment: @Octania Actually, "after expanding", one should remember to NOT study separately real and imaginary parts... What a strange admonestation you wrote.

Comment: @Did Correct, I already deleted my blunder

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$(z-1)(i-2)(i-3)+(z-2)(i-1)(i-3)+(z-3)(i-2)(i-1)=0$$

$$(5-5i)(z-1)+(2-4i)(z-2)+(1-3i)(z-3)=0$$

Comment: Yeah, I already did that. Then I got stuck with a long equation.

Comment: @Tarik How so? This is equivalent to $Az-B=0$ with $$A=(5-5i)+(2-4i)+(1-3i)\qquad B=(5-5i)\cdot1+(2-4i)\cdot2+(1-3i)\cdot3,$$ which leads directly to the solution, no?

Answer (score 0):

Set $i-1=a$, $i-2=b$ and $i-3=c$; then your equation becomes
$$
\frac{z-1}{a}+\frac{z-2}{b}+\frac{z-3}{c}=0
$$
This already cuts out several complications; now multiply both sides by $abc$ and get
$$
bc(z-1)+ac(z-2)+ab(z-3)=0
$$
that becomes
$$
(bc+ac+ab)z=bc+2ac+3ab
$$
Now the task is a bit easier, but let's simplify it further:
\begin{align}
ab&=(i-1)(i-2)=1-3i\\
ac&=(i-1)(i-3)=2-4i\\
bc&=(i-2)(i-3)=5-5i
\end{align}
so we can say
\begin{align}
bc+ac+ab&=5-5i+2-4i+1-3i=8-12i\\
bc+2ac+3ab&=5-5i+2(2-4i)+3(1-3i)=12-22i
\end{align}
Hence the equation is
$$
z=\frac{12-22i}{8-12i}=\frac{6-11i}{2(2-3i)}=
\frac{(6-11i)(2+3i)}{2(2-3i)(2+3i)}=\frac{45-4i}{26}
$$

As you see, it's possible to break the computations into smaller pieces, which also reduces the chances of making errors.